# When a row is duplicated, label if it came from one group, another, or both?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe with duplicated IDs and a group label for each. How could I use `tidyr` or related tools to go from the first data frame to the second? I need to remove the duplicate rows, and label whether each row was present in group "a", group "b", or "both".

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id=c(1,2,2,3,4,4),
             label=c("a","a","b","b","a","b"))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id label
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 a    
3     2 b    
4     3 b    
5     4 a    
6     4 b    

df_desired <- tibble(id=c(1,2,3,4),
                     label=c("a","both","b","both"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id label
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 both 
3     3 b    
4     4 both
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `summarise`

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(label = if_else(length(unique(label)) == 2, "both", first(label)),
              .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id label
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 both 
3     3 b    
4     4 both
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `dplyr` can be:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- tibble(id=c(1,2,2,3,4,4),
             label=c("a","a","b","b","a","b"))
#Code
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(toString) %>%
  mutate(label=ifelse(nchar(label)==1,label,'both'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id label
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 both 
3     3 b    
4     4 both
```